# MAK - Activation via WDS - Error code: 0xc004f038

Tags: domain-name-system, wds, activation, kms

I'm setting up a WDS server in a domain where it's said that MAK is being used for activation of the Windows 7 clients.

Now, I'm getting this error `0xc004f038` which seems to be related to KMS and not MAK. Now, while googling this I've found that this error might occur if there's DNS records for `_VLMCS` in the _tcp section of the domain. And this is what's telling the client that there's a KMS server in the domain.

In the DNS I've found two records for VLMCS. And when I log on to these servers and run `SLMGR.vbs /dlv` I see that KMS is active on both servers. Wouldn't this interfere with MAK activation to Microsoft's servers? Shouldn't KMS be uninstalled for MAK to even work?

Answer (score 1):

KMS activation is the default for non-retail versions of Windows 7. It will be searching DNS for a KMS server and not finding anything, hence the error. If you have a MAK key, you have two options:

1. Manually enter the MAK on each machine that you want to activate (use the 'Change Product key' link in the System Properties page.
2. Download the [VAMT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11936) and host your MAK on there. Setting up an activation server will set up an appropriate DNS entry to allow your clients to discover the server. EDIT: Just noticed that you may already have a VAMT server, so you could host the MAK on there.

Comment: Ah thanx! That was easier than expected :) I also managed to use slmgr and feed the MAK code in there and activate using a script :)